# Solving functional equation $1=e^{−\frac{2}{k}f(ax+bx^2)}+2f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

I want to solve the functional equation
$$1=e^{−\frac{2}{k}f(ax+bx^2)} + 2f(x),$$
where $k>0$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Do you have any ideas on how to tackle this problem?